# System.Media.SoundPlayer, Playing more than 1 sound?

Tags: c#, soundplayer

Is there a way to play more than one sound while let's say the background music is going?

The way I have it is:

```
    public static void PlaySound(string filename)
    {
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
        player.SoundLocation = filename;
        player.Play();
    }
```

Which will play one sound, but using the same "PlaySound" it will basically stop the last sound played and just start a new thread playing the new sound. Is there a way to actually stop this and play more than one sound(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

[Play multiple sounds using SoundPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285294/multiple-sounds-in-soundplayer-in-c-net)
n-c-net

Note the solution with mciSendString at the bottom.