# Play WAV File from Memory using MediaPlayer Class

Tags: c#, wpf

I play a `.wav` sound file when a key is pressed. But there is a delay before playing the sound.

How can I copy the file to memory and play it from `MemoryStream` instead of the Hard Drive?

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter) {
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    Uri uri = new Uri("Sounds\\enter.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    player.Open(uri);
    player.Play();
}
```

---

I'm also using this global keyboard hook, it might be contributing to the delay.

https://gist.github.com/Ciantic/471698

Comment: Doesn't player.Open(uri) do just that? Maybe open the file before you start listening for key presses?

Comment: @Tronald I will try it.

Comment: If you want more control of playback and better performance you may want to look at NAudio instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements are to play from a `MemoryStream` explicitly, then you cant use `MediaPlayer` as far as i know. If it suits you, you can use [`SoundPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) though

```
    soundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(memoryStream);
    soundPlayer.Play();
```

Or

```
    soundPlayer.Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    soundPlayer.Stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    soundPlayer.Play();
```

## Update

`MediaPlayer` has a delay, its not designed to play short sounds in that way.

***This is totally untested***, however, you could try `SoundPlayer` in a `Task.Run` threadpool or background thread. that way you get your buffering performance gain

```
byte[] buffer;

Task.Run(() =>
            {
               soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer()
               soundPlayer.Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
               soundPlayer.Stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
               soundPlayer.Play();
               // or
               soundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(memoryStream);
               soundPlayer.Play();
            });
```

**Or another approach** [Play multiple sounds using SoundPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285294/play-multiple-sounds-using-soundplayer)

```
// Sound api functions
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
static extern Int32 mciSendString(string command, StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize, IntPtr hwndCallback)

...

private void PlayWorker()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    mciSendString("open \"" + FileName + "\" alias " + this.TrackName, sb, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    mciSendString("play " + this.TrackName, sb, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

**Lastly**

If the above still aren't suitable, you might be better of at looking at `DirectSound` or maybe even `nAudio`, or something that has a bit more power in this respect

Comment: I'm not able to use SoundPlayer as it can't play 2 sounds at one time. But I don't have to use MemoryStream, just as long as it can play from memory. I'm just trying to find a way to reduce the delay, I was thinking hard drive speed was causing it.

Comment: Task.Run() would not play 2 at once. DllImport PlayWorker(), `IsBeingPlayed` not found.

Comment: @MattMcManis is being played is just a copy and paste error, and dosnt need to eb there