# Microsoft DirectX Sound on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, directx

I have an old program made with Visual C# 2010. Now I would to use it again so I tried to compile on Visual 2017 Community but it launch an Exception on MicrosoftDirectSound. I understood that it's because is on 32bit so I would ask you if there is any workaround to implement that directx or alternatively what I have to use in the new scenario. I tried with "corflags" too, but it returns a warning about strong named signed.

```
System.BadImageFormatException: ... is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile your program for 32 bits only instead of Any CPU?

Comment: yess...but without success.Basically I have class to capture sound from device audio...without directx now I can't find any device. This class use Microsoft.Directx.DirectSound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound` is part of the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies. They only supported for the .NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0 Runtimes and not the modern .NET 4.x Runtime. You also as you note have to force the use of `/platform:x86`.

Your best option is to use [SlimDX](https://github.com/SlimDX/slimdx) which is intended as a drop-in replacement for the Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies including x64 support. A more modern solution is [SharpDX](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX), but of course you probably shouldn't be using DirectSound in a new app anyhow.

See [DirectX and .NET](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-net/)

> The other thing to keep in mind is that the legacy DirectX Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies are only installed by the legacy DirectX SDK or the deprecated DirectX End-User Runtime Redistribution Package on systems with the .NET 2.0/3.x Runtime enabled. See [Not So DirectSetup](https://walbourn.github.io/not-so-direct-setup/) and [DXSETUP Update](https://walbourn.github.io/dxsetup-update/).

Comment: If I shouldn't be using DirectSound, what should I use instead? I am trying to make a WinForm that plays sound files with basic play/pause functionality. 

I originally intended to use System.Media.SoundPlayer, but it doesn't have pause/resume functionality. Everything I have found on the subject suggests using DirectSound instead, but here you are saying that DirectSound is old and outdated. If SharpDX is also outdated, what do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: DirectSound itself is pretty ancient, but SharpDX is a modern wrapper for most of the DirectX APIs so that's at least a better option than legacy Managed DirectX. XAudio2 is a better option for real-time mixing and DSP, but I'm not sure your sound requirements are really that complex...

Comment: As of 1/30/2021, the SlimDX link in the answer results in an HTTP 403 error.

Comment: Updated links for blog and github archives for slimdx/sharpdx

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1285300/68936, one way to play sounds simultaneously in Windows is to use DirectSound. SharpDX is no longer maintained. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Unity and MonoGame are really the only modern managed solutions for games that are maintained actively. That said, SharpDX works fine since DIrectSound hasn't changed for a decade or more. That said, you should really consider using XAudio2 instead. You could also look at projects like [CSCore](https://github.com/filoe/cscore).