# How to play multiple sounds at once in C#

Tags: c#, audio

I want to be able to play multiple sounds at once. I tried this using multi threading but found they would still play one after the other. Is there a way to get them to play at the same time?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Thread th = new Thread(playSound);
            Thread th1 = new Thread(playSound1);

            th.Start();
            th1.Start();


        }

        public static void playSound()
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer s1 = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\Users\Ben\Documents\c#\note_c.wav");
            s1.Load();
            s1.PlaySync();
        }

        public static void playSound1()
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer s1 = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\Users\Ben\Documents\c#\note_e.wav");
            s1.Load();
            s1.PlaySync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play multiple sounds using SoundPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285294/play-multiple-sounds-using-soundplayer)

Answer (score 2):

How about if we schedule a parallel execution.
Like that:

```
var files = new List<string>() {"note_1.wav", "note_2.wav"};     
Parallel.ForEach(files, (currentFile) => 
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer s1 = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(currentFile);
    s1.Load();
    s1.PlaySync();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these Nuget packages SharpDx
SharpDX.MediaFoundation
SharpDx.Xaudio2 
and use code below, it uses DirectX xAudio2 and constructs a graph with a mixer, it can play WAV 8 and 16 as well

```
public class SoundServices : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets current sound file
    /// </summary>
    string SoundFile { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets current sound stream
    /// </summary>
    public Stream SoundStream { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/Sets looping option, sound will loop if set to true.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsLooping { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Holds the message of last error if any, check it if some feature fails
    /// </summary>
    public string LastErrorMsg { get; private set; }
    //Play control flags
    bool IsPlaying = false;
    bool IsUserStop = false;


    AutoResetEvent Playing;
    float CurrentVolume = 1.0f;
    bool IsInitialized = false;

    SoundStream stream;
    WaveFormat waveFormat;
    AudioBuffer buffer;
    SourceVoice sourceVoice;
    XAudio2 xaudio2;
    MasteringVoice masteringVoice;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes an instance by creating xAudio2 graph and preparing audio Buffers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="soundStream">WAV format sound stream</param>
    /// <param name="loop">Bool indicating to loop sound playing  or not</param>
    public SoundServices(Stream soundStream, bool loop)
    {
        try
        {
            if (soundStream == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("soundStream", "Null is not allowed, please specify a valid stream");
            }
            SoundStream = soundStream;
            SoundFile = null;
            IsLooping = loop;
            //Playing = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            Playing = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            BuildxAudio2Graph();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw e;
        }

    }

    #region Sound Play API
    /// <summary>
    /// Plays the sound stream loaded during initialization
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Task of sound playing</returns>
    public Task PlaySound()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            PlayRepeatAsync();
        });
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Task for starting play of sound buffers using xAudio2 graph
    /// </summary>
    void PlayRepeatAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            IsPlaying = true;
            if (buffer == null)
            {
                //stream = new SoundStream(SoundStream);
                //waveFormat = stream.Format;
                buffer = new AudioBuffer
                {
                    Stream = stream.ToDataStream(),
                    AudioBytes = (int)stream.Length,
                    Flags = SharpDX.XAudio2.BufferFlags.EndOfStream
                };

                if (IsLooping)
                    buffer.LoopCount = AudioBuffer.LoopInfinite;

                sourceVoice.SubmitSourceBuffer(buffer, stream.DecodedPacketsInfo);
                //Close the stream as it is now loaded in buffer already
                //stream.Close();
            }

            sourceVoice.Start();
            Playing.WaitOne();
            sourceVoice.Stop();
            IsPlaying = false;
            sourceVoice.FlushSourceBuffers();
            //xAudio2 graph creation step (5) send the AudioBuffer to sourceVoice
            sourceVoice.SubmitSourceBuffer(buffer, stream.DecodedPacketsInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            LastErrorMsg = "PlayRepeatAsync(): "+ e.Message;
            IsPlaying = false;
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes xAudio2 graph to be used for sound playing
    /// </summary>
    void BuildxAudio2Graph()
    {
        try
        {
            stream = new SoundStream(SoundStream);
            waveFormat = stream.Format;
            //xAudio2 graph creation step (1) Create XAudio2 device
            xaudio2 = new XAudio2();
            //xAudio2 graph creation step (2) Create MasteringVoice and connect it to device
            //*Note: You must use aMasteringVoice to connect to xAudioDevice
            masteringVoice = new MasteringVoice(xaudio2);
            //SetVolume(CurrentVolume);

            //xAudio2 graph creation step (3) Prepare sourceVoice
            sourceVoice = new SourceVoice(xaudio2, waveFormat, true);

            // Adds a  callback check buffer end and Looping option
            sourceVoice.BufferEnd += SourceVoice_BufferEnd;
            //xAudio2 graph creation step (5) send the AudioBuffer to sourceVoice

            IsInitialized = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            LastErrorMsg = "BuildxAudio2Graph(): " + e.Message;
            IsInitialized = false;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Recreates source buffer allowing sound change or loop change
    /// </summary>
    void RecreateBuffer()
    {
        try
        {
            SoundStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream = new SoundStream(SoundStream);
            waveFormat = stream.Format;
            //if (buffer == null)
            {
                //stream = new SoundStream(SoundStream);
                //waveFormat = stream.Format;
                buffer = new AudioBuffer
                {
                    Stream = stream.ToDataStream(),
                    AudioBytes = (int)stream.Length,
                    Flags = SharpDX.XAudio2.BufferFlags.EndOfStream
                };

                if (IsLooping)
                    buffer.LoopCount = AudioBuffer.LoopInfinite;
                sourceVoice.FlushSourceBuffers();
                sourceVoice.SubmitSourceBuffer(buffer, stream.DecodedPacketsInfo);
                //Close the stream as it is now loaded in buffer already
                //stream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            LastErrorMsg = "RecreateBuffer(): " + e.Message;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Changes current audio to a new one
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="soundStream">a stream from wav file</param>
    public void ChangeSoundTo(Stream soundStream, bool Loop)
    {
        try
        {
            IsLooping = Loop;
            SoundStream = soundStream;
            stream = new SoundStream(SoundStream);
            waveFormat = stream.Format;
            sourceVoice = new SourceVoice(xaudio2, waveFormat, true);
            sourceVoice.BufferEnd += SourceVoice_BufferEnd;
            RecreateBuffer();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            IsInitialized = false;
            LastErrorMsg = "ChangeSoundTo(): " + e.Message;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set loop ot no loop
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="loop">True = Loop forever, false = play till end</param>
    public void SetLooping(bool loop)
    {
        if (IsPlaying)
            Stop();
        IsLooping = loop;
        RecreateBuffer();
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Immediately Stops currently playing sound
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsPlaying)
            {
                IsUserStop = true;
                Playing.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            LastErrorMsg = "Stop(): " + e.Message;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets Current Volume
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Current volume</returns>
    public float GetVolume()
    {
        float current = 0.0f;
        try
        {
            if (sourceVoice == null || sourceVoice.IsDisposed) return CurrentVolume;

            sourceVoice.GetVolume(out current);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            LastErrorMsg = "GetVolume(): " + e.Message;
        }
        return current;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the current volume
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newVolume">returns back the current setting for confirmation</param>
    /// <returns>The current set volume</returns>
    public float SetVolume(float newVolume)
    {
        try
        {
            if (newVolume > 1 || newVolume < 0) return GetVolume();
            if (sourceVoice == null || sourceVoice.IsDisposed)
            {
                CurrentVolume = newVolume;
                return newVolume;
            }
            sourceVoice.SetVolume(newVolume, 0);

            return GetVolume();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            LastErrorMsg = "SetVolume(): " + e.Message;
            return 0.0f;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// End of buffer event handler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    private void SourceVoice_BufferEnd(IntPtr obj)
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine($"buffer end reached with looping {IsLooping}");
        if (!IsLooping)
        {
            if (IsPlaying && !IsUserStop)
                Playing.Set();
            else if(IsUserStop)
            {
                IsUserStop = false;
            }
        }

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (sourceVoice != null && !sourceVoice.IsDisposed)
        {
            sourceVoice.DestroyVoice();

            sourceVoice.Dispose();
        }
        if (buffer != null && buffer.Stream != null)
            buffer.Stream.Dispose();
        if (masteringVoice != null && !masteringVoice.IsDisposed)
            masteringVoice.Dispose();
        if (xaudio2 != null && !xaudio2.IsDisposed)
            xaudio2.Dispose();
    }

    ~SoundServices()
    {
        if (sourceVoice != null && !sourceVoice.IsDisposed)
        {
            sourceVoice.DestroyVoice();

            sourceVoice.Dispose();
        }
        if (buffer != null && buffer.Stream != null)
            buffer.Stream.Dispose();
        if (masteringVoice != null && !masteringVoice.IsDisposed)
            masteringVoice.Dispose();
        if (xaudio2 != null && !xaudio2.IsDisposed)
            xaudio2.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And you can use multiple SoundServices instances as you need:

```
var sp = new SoundServices(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(WavFileName)), true);
            if (sp != null)
                sp.PlaySound();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
static extern Int32 mciSendString(string command, StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize, IntPtr hwndCallback);
```

Usage:

```
       mciSendString(@"open path\to\your\file.wav type waveaudio alias anAliasForYourSound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        mciSendString(@"play anAliasForYourSound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
  mciSendString(@"open path\to\your\anotherFile.wav type waveaudio alias anAliasForYourAnotherSound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        mciSendString(@"play anAliasForYourAnotherSound", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't start threads at exactly same time but in this case you can improve your code by loading the sounds before starting the threads:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer s1 = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(
      @"c:\Users\Ben\Documents\c#\note_c.wav");
    s1.Load();

    System.Media.SoundPlayer s2 = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(
      @"c:\Users\Ben\Documents\c#\note_e.wav");
    s2.Load();

    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    Thread th = new Thread(() => playSound(s1));
    Thread th1 = new Thread(() => playSound(s2));

    th.Start();
    th1.Start();
}

public static void playSound(System.Media.SoundPlayer s)
{
    s.PlaySync();
}
```

Otherwise you'll need to implement a synchronization system.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use DirectX xAudio2 via SharpDX , you can find it here:
https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/XAudio2/PlaySound

It works perfectly , but it would be a bit tricky to make the code better, by utilizing Events & tasks instead of the while loop and sync execution, and to be able to load the xAudio2 graph dynamically to change the sound without reconstructing the whole graph.